# How to get Jquery working from an externally loaded html inside a div

Tags: jquery, flash, html

I'm setting up a page that uses a flash menu to load html pages into a div container by the following call:

```
on (release){
getURL("javascript:getPage('test.html')");
}
```

The loading works fine, but some of my pages had specific jquery scripts and that's where I've struck out so far.

I assumed all I needed to do was transfer the script importations, css stylesheets and the jquery functions to my main document, but it won't work.

I also tried importing the html as a the complete html, which works on it's own, but not when imported into the main document.

Most recently I heard I should try shifting the jquery function calls to the end of the loaded document, to after the content, but that didn't help either...

My scripts work, just not when imported, so I suppose my question is how can I make the main- and imported documents play nice with each other? What say you we make this a jump-start tutorial for all us noobs to reference?

Comment: Are you loading a complete HTML page (starting with <!DOCTYPE or <html) into a div? Or are you loading a subset?

Comment: Hi, and thanks for the reply. I tried both ways, importing both just the content and a full version of the page, which works fine stand-alone, btw, but neither approach worked for me.

Comment: What does your question imply? What's the difference?

Let's back-track, if I were to try to activate the code after loading up the content, where would I include the .js and .css imports, in the main document head, or the loaded document head?

Answer (score 0):

So it depends on what the scripts on the loaded page is doing, you can look at the [live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) function in jQuery.

Alternatively you can make use of a callback function in your AJAX call to set up the jquery event handling for the loaded page.

Comment: Forgive my uninformedness, but how would I go about using a callback function in my ajax to set up the event handling for the loaded page?
Sounds like something I might want to do.

Comment: @melker It depends a bit on how you are doing the AJAX call. I see you tagged the question jQuery so you can use some like the jQuery load() function as described here: http://api.jquery.com/load/. Notice that there is a callback function defined as one of the parameters of load. That function is executed after the load is completed.

Comment: I was certain I had posted this already, but thing is guys, I'm still stuck and can't see the forrest from the trees. I'm including a couple of workfiles I'm having trouble with, and would greatly appreciate it if one of you could muster the time to check them out. Scouts honor they're clean. Holler back.
http://bit.ly/kJeeWi

Comment: ramdhanie @bpeterson76 Been oggling the live, get and load functions, but am unsure of which syntax to use to change my initial function call from flash and, still, what could be wrong with my script initiations. Idk. Wish someone could just point out what I'm doing wrong so I can do better next time. Shucks.

Answer (score 0):

Using the ready() command often helps things (it is a Dom listener) as well as moving code to the bottom, which some will argue makes the page load more efficient (a point for another post)

However, this question comes up a lot and 9 times out of 10 it's related to the script or Jquery link itself being invalid in the page that it's included from.  For example, if the page doing the jquery is in the /scripts folder and it calls jquery.js that also resides in the /scripts folder, it works.  However, when you include the file into index.htm that resides in the / folder, suddenly the link to jquery is looking for a jquery file in /, not in /scripts.  The easy way to check this is to view source and click on the links (works great in Chrome) to see if the files are found.  If so, you're good...if not, play with your link paths.  Better yet, use [CDN hosted versions](http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery#CDN_Hosted_jQuery) of code when possible.

And, for noobs, it is possible to include jQuery in files outside of the document head and they still work just fine.  My company uses that method on webforms that get included via (ugh) iFrame in other's sites.  It's serving up hundreds of webforms flawlessly!

One last thing.  As a UI engineer for many years, I've been seeing a very clear trend of Flash menus really dying off in a hurry (which is also followed by a serious drop-off in Flash developer hiring)  They often have serious SEO issues, take more effort to maintain, and can have other performance implications.  Chances are these days that you can get a Javascript, pure CSS, or HTML5 menu that does the same thing or better and is 100% w3 compliant.  Maybe personal preference, but definitely a growing trend to consider as you continue to learn.

Comment: Enlightening. My links should be allright. I've got a couple of them that link directly to google.apis, but the others are in the root directory and use src instead of href. As stated, the imported pages work on their own, but not after importation to the main doc.

Comment: Ps. A shame about flash not being appreciated anymore. I totally get it, but would still emphasize that if you positively, absolutely have to animate the proverbial he** out of everything in the room... accept no substitute. Not to mention coding, keyframes, sounds and such. It's just a neat, limitless package, imho. Sure updating your workfile is a toil, but it is possible to cultivate one's menus dynamically from xml or the such.

Comment: @Melker, src vs href shouldn't make a difference.  Try making all your links absolute (use full http://www.something.com) and see if that makes a difference.  BTW, Flash's weakness isn't it's nature, it's Adobe.  They go and radically re-write Actionscript from scratch causing companies and developers to spend unnecessary money to retrain constantly every two years.  Add that to criminal software costs and VERY poor quality code, and you've got a perfect storm.  Then, just to add insult to injury, they go and pick a fight with Apple.  Not too bright!

Comment: That would explain your take on the subject. True enough, I still use actionscript 2.0 and don't see a need to change my ways. Indeed, I was slightly appalled by the standardized components of later makes. Mainly because you learn better by doing the actual footwork yourself. I guess the common vibe would be that the suite's gone from bad to worse, now that you mention it. I actually wanted to install MX on min win7 machine, but the installer was outdated. Go figure.

Comment: Been messing around with this over the evening, but still having difficulties sorting this out. Checked out your website, but couldn't find an e-mail so I uploaded a couple of files for you to check out if you would. http://bit.ly/kJeeWi